# how to extract dkim value of Authentication-Results field from message header using java mail

Tags: jakarta-mail

I want to extract dkim value of Authentication-Results field from email header. 
I tried with below code and below is the response of code for reference.

```
code:

String Auth[] =messages[(int) i].getHeader("Authentication-Results");
            System.out.println("Authentication-Results :  " + 
Arrays.toString(Auth) );
```

**output**:

```
 Authentication-Results:mta4458.mail.bf1.yahoo.com  from=xyz.com; 
domainkeys=neutral (no sig);  from=xyz-com.20150623.gappssmtp.com; 
dkim=pass (ok)
```

**I Want the following output:**

```
   dkim=pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the string.  It doesn't seem to use the standard MIME format that other headers use so you'll need to write your own parser.  The syntax is specified by [RFC 5451](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5451#page-8).

Comment: Thanks, @BillShannon

So, it means there is no such direct method which can give me my required output ?

Comment: Correct, you have to write it yourself.